# How to render a random trajectory animation infinitely, on some interval?

Tags: reactjs

What I would like is to create a code that 'shoots' out some image from the center of the screen to some random trajectory.

Here is the descriptional code I would like to achieve:

```
class Name extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
           <img animation moving from centre to some random trajectory>
           after few seconds...
           <another img animation (the same one) moving from centre to some other random trajectory>
           <do it many more times, until event occurs that will stop it>
        );
    }
}
```

I have made components that create interface, and that render an image animation of movement from centre to some random trajectory, but only once. I don't know how to make it repeatedly.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
import {CreateEnvironment} from './components/createEnvironment';
import {SheepsStart} from './components/sheepsStart';

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
render(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CreateEnvironment />
            <SheepsStart />
        </React.Fragment>
        );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Component CreateEnvironment is irrelevant, it creates 3 drawing divs.

Component SheepsStart:

```
import React from 'react';
import {CreateSheeps} from './createSheeps';
import sheep from '../images/sheep.png';

export class SheepsStart extends React.Component { 
render(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>             
        <CreateSheeps src = {sheep} alt = "Sheep"/>            
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

Styled component, which I needed so I could insert random `@keyframes`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { sheepWantsToEscape } from './KeyFrames';

export const CreateSheeps = styled.img`
width:2.5%;
z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
left:48.75%;
bottom:48.75%;
animation: ${sheepWantsToEscape} 4s;
animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-timing-function:linear;
`

export default CreateSheeps;
```

Component with `@keyframes` with random trajectory coordinates.Function `createTrajectory` calculates coordinates, and returns an array of two.

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import {createTrajectory} from './helperFunction';

let coordinates = createTrajectory();
export const sheepWantsToEscape = keyframes`
0% {
left:48.75%;
bottom:48.75%;
}
100% {
left:${coordinates[0]}%;
bottom:${coordinates[1]}%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only an example, if you point out what you've tried out I'll can be more specific:

```js
const base = 100;

class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
   myStyle : {
     marginTop: base,
      marginLeft: -base,
    }
  }
  
 plusMinus = () => Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1; 
 randomize = () => {

  this.setState({
   myStyle: {
     marginTop: Math.random()*base*this.plusMinus(),
     marginBottom: Math.random()*base*this.plusMinus(),
    },
  });
 }

  render() {
    return <div><img
 style={{...this.state.myStyle}}   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/200px-React-icon.svg.png" />
    <button onClick={this.randomize}>move</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vya19fz2/

Comment: Please take a look at my question from yesterday, it has all the code.

Comment: You have to update the current question, possibly woth a working snippet. Out for lunch now!

Comment: Updated it! Please take a look after lunch. Cheers!